# Query Opportunity Type (e.g New Business) via API fails with Bind Variable

Tags: soql, rest-api, api, soap-api, python

I am trying to get all won opportunities that are new business only for example.

```
r = requests.get('{}/services/data/v41.0/query'.format(instance_url),params = {'q':'SELECT Name, Type from Opportunity where IsWon=true and CloseDate={0} and type!={1}'.format(today,'Renewal')}, headers=header)
```

Unfortunately, this brings me the error:

> [{"message":"\nCloseDate=2017-12-11 and type!=Renewal\n                              ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:87\nBind variables only allowed in Apex code","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]

If I leave the type away it works fine, but giving me, all won opportunities even renewals for example.

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.format(today, 'Renewal')
```

Use:

```
.format('today', '\'Renewal\'')
```

You want your first argument to be a **[Date Literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)**, and the second argument to get merged in as a literal string. That way your filters would read:

```
WHERE CloseDate = today AND Type != 'Renewal'
```

Comment: Awesome, you are right with the idea. Thank you very much.
One small edit.  Today is a datetime.date() and therefore the right solution will be:
     r = requests.get('{}/services/data/v41.0/query'.format(instance_url),params = {'q':'SELECT Name, Type from Opportunity where IsWon=true and CloseDate={0} and type!=\'{1}''.format(today,'Renewal')}, headers=header)